# HTTPS redirect, exclude script parameters from URL

Tags: redirects, https, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My goals:

```
1. http://example.com/page/index.php -> https://example.com/page/
2. http://example.com/page/ -> https://example.com/page/
3. http://www.example.com/page/ -> https://example.com/page/
4. Any nonexistent file or directory requests -> index.php?&q=$1 for further processing.
```

The following rules work fine, but only after a redirect in the browser URL instead of a clean URL. For example, if I request:

```
https://example.com/page/
```

I see

```
https://example.com/index.php?&q=page/
```

How do I hide `index.php?&q=page` and show `https://example.com/page/` in the URL instead? Before I added HTTPS redirect it worked fine for HTTP. I tried 2 solutions with the same result.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
```

#### Solution 1:

```
#1 solution:
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?&q=$1 [QSA]
```

#### Solution 2:

```
#2 solution:
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?&q=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: Is your `.htaccess` file located in the document root? Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file? Any other `.htaccess` files in subdirectories? Just to confirm... you didn't try both solutions _at the same time_? Make sure you've cleared your browser cache.

Comment: 1. .htaccess is in the document root
2. No other htaccess in subdirectories
3. Only one solution at time
4. Cache was cleared

htaccess contents

Options All -Indexes -Includes -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks

Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
Header unset X-Powered-By
Header unset ETag
FileETag None

Comment: For all first three points, look at the `Redirect` directive: far enough to handle all simple redirection needs, no need to use the more powerful (hence more complicated) `mod_rewrite` module.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I hide `index.php?&q=page` and show `https://example.com/page/` in the URL instead? Before I added HTTPS redirect it worked fine for HTTP.

The code you posted should not result in such a "redirect". And neither should adding the "HTTPS redirect" have affected this.

Unless... you initially added the "HTTPS redirect" at the end of your `.htaccess` file, after the *internal rewrite* to `index.php?&q=$1`. In which case, you would have expected a request for either `http://example.com/page/` or `https://www.example.com/page/` or `http://www.example.com/page/` to have resulted in such an *external redirect* (as opposed to an *internal rewrite*) to `https://example.com/index.php?&q=page/`. HOWEVER, you have stated that requesting `https://example.com/page/` (already HTTPS and non-www) results in such a redirect - that would not happen under this scenario.

It's still possible that an earlier (erroneous) redirect has been cached (301's are persistently cached by the browser) and this is what you are seeing here. However, you've stated (in comments) that the (browser? and all intermediary?) cache(s) has been cleared. So, that just leaves "something else" (ie. *something else* external to the directives you've posted that sets a 3xx HTTP status)?

---

*Additional notes, not directly related to your main problem:*

> 1. `http://example.com/page/index.php` -> `https://example.com/page/`
>
>    ```
>    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/ [NC]
>    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [L,NE,R=301]
>    ```

Condition #1 is not satisfied by any of the directives you've posted. The directives you've posted above would only redirect a request for `/index.php` in the document root, not `/page/index.php` as you've stated. To redirect `/page/index.php`, you would naturally need to include the `/page` path segment when matching the requested URL (and pass this through to the *substitution*). For example:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /page/index\.php\ HTTP/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(page/)index\.php$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,NE,R=301]
```

However, I suspect an "any directory" solution would be required. In which case you could do something like the following:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\ HTTP/ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)index\.php$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,NE,R=301]
```

---

> ```
> RewriteRule (.*) index.php?&q=$1 [QSA]
> ```

You should probably include the `L` (`last`) flag on this directive, in case you add any more directives later in the file. (This would have prevented an erroneous *redirect* if you had added the HTTPS redirect at the end by mistake.)

And, unless you have a specific requirement, you should be rewriting to `index.php?q=$1` (no `&` after the `?`). For example:

```
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?q=$1 [QSA,L]
```